# Yet another optimization with rvalue reference &&. Simply rename fields

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Let's consider the next code:

```
struct Channel;  // somewhere declared
using iter_t = std::set<Channel>::iterator;

std::set<Channel> myset;
std::pair<iter_t, bool> emplaced = myset.emplace(arg1,arg2);
```

Then `emplaced.first` contains iterator to element, `emplaced.second` indicates if element was added, or already exist. *first* and *second* is not clear as for me. I want to rename this fields:

```
struct ChannelAddedResult
{
    iter_t channelIter;
    bool wasAdded;
public: // --- Functions, constructors ---
    ChannelAddedResult(std::pair<iter_t, bool> &&pa) {
       this->channel = pa.first;
       this->added = pa.second;
    }
 };
```

This constructor copies values. And here is no profit from rvalue reference. Right?
But how can I convert `std::pair<iter_t, bool>` to `ChannelAddedResult`? This types are equivalent. So `C`-style conversation could look like:

```
union CarUni {
  std::pair<iter_t, bool>  pair;
  ChannelAddedResult       car;
}
// Use
CarUni u;
u.pair = myset.emplace(arg1,arg2);
auto ch = *u.car.channelIter;
bool a = u.car.wasAdded;
```

This allows to achieve rename without additional copies. May be `C`-casting `(ChannelAddedResult)emplaced_pair` will do the same work, but it is deprecated in C++. These 2 conversions are dangerous from the point of type safety.

Is there a C++11 way for such conversion?

Comment: Where is this "C-style conversation" you're talking about? That's all C++. And C-style casts (which you have *not used* in your example) are not deprecated in C++. Overall, your code seems fine and not in any way "dangerous from the point of type safety". What is your concern, exactly?

Comment: `std::pair<iter_t, bool> &emplaced == myset.emplace(arg1,arg2);` should be `std::pair<iter_t, bool> &emplaced = myset.emplace(arg1,arg2);`

Comment: `std::pair<iter_t, bool> &emplaced == myset.emplace(arg1,arg2);` please avoid posting code that does not compile for reasons unrelated to your question.  I guess there are two typos, but...  if there are typos there how many other random features of your code are typos you did not intend?

Comment: Second, how expensive do you think copying a std set iterator and a bool is?  How hard to optimize do you think it is?

Comment: *expensive* - here 2 copies does not meter. But this is only snippet. In some more extended code i.e. emplace 100000000000 channels could slow down application. This example implements **idea of renaming fields**. I can imagine other implementations and variations.

Comment: fixed == to = .

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to copy, move:

```
ChannelAddedResult(std::pair<iter_t, bool> &&pa)
    : channel(std::move(pa.first))
    , added(std::move(pa.second))
{}
```

Though for types like `bool`s and iterators there is no real difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small sample program to show how I might have given it a try.
What I get from your question is that you want to rename the `first` and `second` of pair with your custom typed name i.e. `channelIter` and `wasAdded`.

I took your sample code and made a simpler program out of it.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct Channel
{
    int _a; // Declaring 2 simple args
    int _b;

    Channel(int a, int b) : _a(a), _b(b) {} 

    // Need to provide a < operator for custom datatype
    bool operator<(Channel const & rhs) const {
        return (this->_a < rhs._a) || (this->_b < rhs._b);
    }
};

using iter_t = std::set<Channel>::iterator;

struct ChannelAddedResult
{
    iter_t _channelIter;
    bool   _wasAdded;

    ChannelAddedResult(std::pair<iter_t, bool> && pa) 
                      : _channelIter(pa.first), _wasAdded(pa.second) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::set<Channel> myset;
    auto u  = ChannelAddedResult(myset.emplace(5, 6));
    auto ch = *u._channelIter; // Access pair.first
    bool a  = u._wasAdded;     // Access pair.second

    std::cout << "ch._a => [" << ch._a << "] ch._b => [" << ch._b << "]\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with -std=c++11

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 set_sample.cpp -o set_sample
```

Output

```
$ ./set_sample
ch._a => [5] ch._b => [6]
```

Point to be understood here is that, `ChannelAddedResult(std::pair<iter_t, bool> && pa)` is an rvalue reference and should be passed an rvalue to be used efficiently. So it should be used like `ChannelAddedResult(myset.emplace(5, 6))`. Here `myset.emplace(5,6)` is an rvalue. So no copy would be created.

On the contrary if the usage had been as following, a useless copy is being created in between. Passing an lvalue to an rvalue reference defeats the whole purpose.

```
auto val = myset.emplace(5,6);
auto u  = ChannelAddedResult(val); // val is an lvalue
```

The above mentioned code won't compile though. To make it work you would need to upgrade the signature as -

```
ChannelAddedResult(std::pair<iter_t, bool> const & pa) 
                  : _channelIter(pa.first), _wasAdded(pa.second) {}
```

Now it will work with both rvalue and lvalue.
Since we are already copying the data of `std::pair` into other variables, the usage of rvalue reference doesn't add much to the performance. Better use `T const & pa` rather than `T && pa`, in this situation.

Comment: Right. Thank you for the full program. I tried to make my post as short as possible. But here as far as I understand `&&pa` does not any meter since it works exactly as `const&pa`

Comment: @kyb : Your understanding is not correct. `T && pa` is an rvalue reference and will directly use the value of `myset.emplace(5, 6)` (since it is an rvalue in my program). On the contrary, making use of `T const & pa` instead of `T && pa` would have created a temporary copy for the same, used ithe temporary, and then later destroy the temporary copy.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add more details catering to your doubt. Go through it once again.